# Oracle SQL: Trigger to add grants after creating view

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with vendor application that uses Oracle database. To save the content it uses database tables, which are queried by using views. I do not have any control over that code.
Because of security I gave access to those views to special reporting user, which can only select entries from it.

Whenever some major change is made in the application it drops the appropriate view and creates it anew. Of course all grants are lost and since the changes are made rarely it is easy to forget to backup up and restore them afterwards.

I consulted DBA and he suggested to write a trigger to save grants in temporary table, after which the entries can be used to restore grants. Saving part works fine as expected:

```
create or replace TRIGGER RECORD_GRANTS_ONDROP 
BEFORE DROP ON MYUSER.SCHEMA 
BEGIN
    IF ora_dict_obj_owner = 'MYUSER' and ora_dict_obj_name not like 'TEMP_PRIV%' and ora_dict_obj_type='VIEW' then
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TEMP_PRIV AS SELECT ''GRANT '' || PRIVILEGE || '' ON MYUSER.'' || TABLE_NAME || '' TO '' || GRANTEE PRIVILEGE_x FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE not in (''MYUSER'',''PUBLIC'') AND TABLE_NAME=''' || ora_dict_obj_name || '''';
    ELSE null;
    END IF;
END;
```

As a result I get a table with all grants assigned to the said view.
For restoring I wanted to run similar trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER RESTORE_GRANTS_AFTERCREATE
AFTER CREATE ON MYUSER.SCHEMA 
BEGIN
    IF ora_dict_obj_owner = 'MYUSER' and ora_dict_obj_type='VIEW' then
        FOR loop_counter IN (select '''' || privilege_x || '''' AS privilege_x from temp_priv)
        LOOP
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE loop_counter.privilege_x;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(loop_counter.privilege_x);
        END LOOP;
    ELSE null;
    END IF;
    NULL;
END;
```

I will note here that is just basic test of concept without any proper checks, so just focus on the big issue here.

When I try to create a view now I get an error:

```
Error report -
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 5
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

This can only mean that the view is not created at the time when trigger tries to add grants. Syntax wise I successfully ran the command:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON MYUSER.CR_STATUS_TABLE TO SOMEUSER';
END
```

But when I try to run it using for, or just by itself in 'after create' trigger I get the same error. 
Does anyone knows how to approach this, and I would like to avoid jobs at all costs if possible.

Comment: i'm assuming you have no control over the 'dropping the view and recreates it' as a CREATE OR REPLACE views would avoid your problem

Comment: None what so ever. I would immediately go for that approach and avoid all of this.

Comment: What if you replicated the database such that you could do anything you want with it for reporting purposes, say using data guard? Crazy thought...

Comment: There are multiple reasons why that is not a good idea: technically looking it's 400GB replication that must be ran on top notch hardware, which doesn't justify the cost. Oracle charges a license for all servers that are ON and they are really expensive, not to mention on extended support at this point. Years before I came on-board bunch of reporting systems were set to run this way. Implementing a change in that manner would take up a lot of money and man hours to accomodate the switch.

Comment: @WhiteCleric - you could recreate the views in the reporting user schema, instead of it just having privileges on the real ones; though then it would need privileges on the underlying table instead, and would still potentially be a lot more maintenance. Just another crazy thought *8-)

Comment: @WhiteCleric it doesn't have to be on separate hardware...or put it on a cheap commodity hw setup since performance isn't necessarily Paramount

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring whether this is a good idea... you're getting that error because you're overthinking your string manipulation. What you're putting into your table looks OK. The problem is when you get it back out. The value in the table is already a string, so you don't need to then enclose it in another set of quotes.

What you're actually running is the equivalent of:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''GRANT SELECT ON MYUSER.CR_STATUS_TABLE TO SOMEUSER''';
```

which will also throw "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement", rather than your standalone, working, version:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON MYUSER.CR_STATUS_TABLE TO SOMEUSER';
```

If you swapped the order of your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and `DBMS_OUTPUT` calls you'd see the problem statement *before* it ran, which would be more helpful - you'd see those quotes as part of the string.

So in your second trigger, instead of doing:

```
FOR loop_counter IN (select '''' || privilege_x || '''' AS privilege_x from temp_priv)
LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE loop_counter.privilege_x;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(loop_counter.privilege_x);
END LOOP;
```

just do:

```
FOR loop_counter IN (select privilege_x from temp_priv)
LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(loop_counter.privilege_x);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE loop_counter.privilege_x;
END LOOP;
```

However, this still won't work; it will now get ORA-30511: invalid DDL operation in system triggers. This is presumably because of the restrictions [shown in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-F6473AD0-75D2-4E36-8B15-F93F0B5A8B79):

> Trigger cannot do DDL operations on object that caused event to be generated.
>
> DDL on other objects is limited to compiling an object, creating a trigger, and creating, altering, and dropping a table.

You said "it is easy to forget to backup up and restore them afterwards" but you're going to have to put a robust process around your upgrades to make sure that does happen.

You can change your process to have a separate step at the end of every upgrade that is always run, which executes all of those stored statements for all objects - maybe skipping or ignoring errors from anything that wasn't recreated - and then drops the `temp_priv` table.

But you don't really want to (try to) create that temporary table in a trigger anyway - if two views are dropped, the first creates it, the second fails because it already exists. A perhaps more realistic approach might be to create that table *once* now:

```
create table TEMP_PRIV (PRIVILEGE_X VARCHAR2(4000));
```

and then utilise it for all subsequent upgrades, either by populating it with all grants for all views as a single step before the upgrade starts:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_PRIVS (PRIVILEGE_X)
SELECT 'GRANT ' || PRIVILEGE || ' ON MYUSER.' || TABLE_NAME || ' TO ' || GRANTEE
FROM USER_VIEWS UV
JOIN USER_TAB_PRIVS UTP ON UTP.TABLE_NAME = UV.VIEW_NAME
WHERE UTP.GRANTEE not in ('MYUSER','PUBLIC');
```

or if you're still worried about possibly forgetting that step then with a trigger to do it one view at a time as they are dropped:

```
create or replace TRIGGER RECORD_GRANTS_ONDROP 
BEFORE DROP ON MYUSER.SCHEMA 
BEGIN
    IF ora_dict_obj_owner = 'MYUSER' and ora_dict_obj_name not like 'TEMP_PRIV%' and ora_dict_obj_type='VIEW' then
      INSERT INTO TEMP_PRIV
      SELECT 'GRANT ' || PRIVILEGE || ' ON MYUSER.' || TABLE_NAME || ' TO ' || GRANTEE
      FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS
      WHERE GRANTEE not in ('MYUSER','PUBLIC')
      AND TABLE_NAME = ora_dict_obj_name;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Then at the end of the upgrade process reissue all the statements in the table and clear it down ready for next time:

```
DECLARE
    missing_view EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(missing_view, -942);
BEGIN
    FOR loop_counter IN (select privilege_x from temp_priv)
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(loop_counter.privilege_x);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE loop_counter.privilege_x;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN missing_view THEN
              -- report but otherwise ignore
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/

TRUNCATE TABLE temp_priv;
```

If you go with the simpler non-trigger approach then it will re-grant existing privileges, but that's OK. And the exception handler means it'll report but skip any views that were dropped and not recreated, if that ever happens. (You'll still have to deal with any *new* view of course; your after-create trigger wouldn't have helped with that anyway.) And note that I've truncated the table, rather than dropped it - so it's still there, empty, when the next upgrade comes around and wants to populate it.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I replaced the output and everything and just tried to run EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON MYUSER.CR_STATUS_TABLE TO SOMEUSER'; without the loop. I get the same error. It is definitely not the syntax. The command runs fine on it's own, but not in the trigger.

Comment: @WhiteCleric - do you really get the same error? Or has the ORA-00900 changed to ORA-30511: invalid DDL operation in system triggers?